# TableView save after changing color of a view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with some results of Firebase in the cell. All cells have one white view. I have added the swiping action "venduto" and I want that when I tap on this button the color of the view become green. It works exactly but if I change viewController and get back on it, the color of the view returns white.

How can I save the change?

Please use Swift.

Comment: You should set the new state on Firebase and not only fetch data from there!

Answer (score 2):

When you fill your **array/dictionary**(whatever you are using to populate tableview) with firebase data, just **add one more field** to it and maintain its state when you click on the button to change the colour of the cell.
Eg:
you added your **new field as a key value pair**

```
{
   isvendutoClicked : true
}
```

then **change the state** of this key on buttons click event:

```
if isvendutoClicked {

   isvendutoClicked = false

}else{

 isvendutoClicked = true

}
```

After that **check the state** of this new field in "cellForRow" method of table view and **set the colour** of the view accordingly.
Eg:

```
if isvendutoClicked {

   yourCellView.backgroundColour = Green Colour

}else{

   yourCellView.backgroundColour = White Colour

}
```

So whenever the table will load, no matter from the same screen or while navigating back from other screen, it will show the colour of the cell according to state of that extra field which you added.

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should store states for cells (items) in your ViewController if it only UI feature. If state for item should be stored between application runs, you need to update data in Firebase.

```
class SomeVC: UIViewController {
    var states = [IndexPath:Bool]()

    func toggleStateForItem(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var newValue = true
        if let previous = states[indexPath] {
            newValue = !previous
        }
        states[indexPath] = newValue
    }
}
```

You can change `Bool` to `Color` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your data model. You would have one value for the color. Update this value every time you change the color of your cell.

You can run something like this:

```
dbRef.child("yourKey").child("yourKey").updateChildValues(["yourKey": yourValue])
```

I don't know your current data model but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can bind a property(such as isSelected) to the model which is the data to render the UI .When the button is selected or deselected,then set the  button's selected property to the isSelected property of the model,then call reloadData.Then save the data to plist or prefernce,then next time you just check the plist file if not exist ,load the not changed data,else load the plist data. Then you need to rewrite the model getter method in the cell's implementation,according the isSelected,if the value is yes,set the background color white else set the backgroundColor green.